# Getting E820 memory map from Windows

Tags: windows, memory

Is there a Win32 API or documented ddk function to get E820 memory map information?  I am trying to avoid a hack but use documented API to get to this information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WMI and the Device APIs to get the actual reserved memory ranges, which is more accurate than the BIOS-reported ones. If you really want the BIOS one, you'll have to write a device driver.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!  Please could you be more specific about the device APIs you are referring to?  Also, I have drivers as well.  So, info on how I could get E820 data from a driver would be useful as well.  Thanks.